# How to make gulp not finish task before it's done?

Tags: node.js, gulp

I have this gulp task, and it works fine, but when looking at the log, it always says Starting Task, then immediately Finished Task, then it starts logging everything. How do I make it wait until everything is complete until it says it's finished? I think it's due to the function being async so done() gets called right away, but I'm not sure what to do.

**gulp function**

```
gulp.task("img-projects", function(done) {
  gulp.src('projects/*/images/**/*.*')
    .pipe(imagemin())
    .pipe(rename(function (path) {
        path.dirname = path.dirname.replace('/images','');
        console.log('path');
        return path;
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('public'));

    done();
});
```

**output:**

```
[19:11:55] Starting 'js-projects'...
[19:11:55] Finished 'js-projects' after 34 ms
[19:11:55] path
[19:11:55] path
[19:11:55] path
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to add is an `on('end', ...)` listener to wait until the gulp stream is complete before calling `done()`:

```
gulp.task("img-projects", function(done) {
  gulp.src('projects/*/images/**/*.*')
    .pipe(imagemin())
    .pipe(rename(function (path) {
        path.dirname = path.dirname.replace('/images','');
        console.log('path');
        return path;
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('public'))
    .on('end', done);
});
```

Sources:
[How do you run a gulp "on end" task but only at the end of the current task?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26100666/how-do-you-run-a-gulp-on-end-task-but-only-at-the-end-of-the-current-task)

gulp API (docs for `src()`/`dest()`/etc): https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/tree/master/docs/api

node.js streams API which provides `on(...)`: https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html

similar issue: https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/issues/1181#issuecomment-126694791

Answer (score 0):

Try,

The gulp functions are async

```
gulp.task("img-projects", function() {
  return gulp.src('projects/*/images/**/*.*')
    .pipe(imagemin())
    .pipe(rename(function (path) {
        path.dirname = path.dirname.replace('/images','');
        console.log('path');
        return path;
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('public'));
});
```

Comment: I need to call done() to make the watcher functions work